# How to create live changing text in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, terminal, console

How to live changing in ruby, I receive API but it looks like:

```
the number is 1
the number is 2
the number is 3
```

it's normal because inside the loop and when I use `cls` on windows or `clear` on Debian, it clears the whole text on the terminal.
I want to make it one line, any suggestions?

Comment: This might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43075/how-to-change-the-contents-of-a-line-on-the-terminal-as-opposed-to-writing-a-new

Comment: so, I turn the ruby code to call system on Unix/Debian on it to trace the mouse? I'll try it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _"trace the mouse"_. You use (ANSI) escape sequences to move the cursor and / or clear the current line. Of course, you don't use a bash script to do so, you just print the sequences using Ruby.